# Passing TableQuery object as a parameter results in strange type error in Slick/Scala but not when injected

Tags: postgresql, scala, functional-programming, slick

I am writing a function to persist some data to a Slick postgres database. Here is my table persisting `ClientRow` objects:

```scala
class ClientTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ClientRow](tag, "clients") {
  def clientId = column[Long]("client_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  ...
  override def * =
        (clientId, phoneNumber, firstName, lastName, trainerId, dateRegistered) <> (ClientRow.tupled, ClientRow.unapply _)
}
```

I tried writing the following function to inject the table and database dependencies through composition:

```scala
type PersistClient[A <: AbstractTable[_]] =
    DatabaseDef => TableQuery[A] => ClientInfo => Future[ClientId]

val persist: PersistClient[ClientTable] = db =>
      clients =>
        info => {
          val action = clients.returning(
            clients.map(_.clientId) += toRow(info)
          )
          db.run(action).map(constructId(_))
    }
```

Here ClientInfo and ClientId are just case classes with data. `toRow` has signature `ClientInfo => ClientRow`, it converts the strongly typed/highly structured data in the Info object to more primitive data for SQL. `constructId` creates a string ID out of the Long for logging readability (I like `id.client.<number>`)

Under `toRow` I get the following error:

```scala
type mismatch;
 found   : messager.Client.persistence.ClientRow
 required: Long
```

Strangely, if I write the same function while injecting the dependencies into the class that houses this function as so:

```scala
val persistClient: ClientInfo => Future[ClientId] = info => {
      val action = clients.returning(clients.map(_.clientId)) += toRow(info)
      db.run(action).map(constructId(_))
    }
```

Here `clients` and `db` are the same types as before, but are just injected into the class as dependencies rather than inputs to a function. What gives? Why can't my nice curried code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the argument to `clients.returning` is a insert that returns the number of rows changed. That doesn't look right, and is different from the version you have that works.

Comment: OMG I see it now! there parentheses are so sneaky... Thank you!